# How to turn row values to fields? Using row values as guide?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got this table:

```
Col1 -- Col2
ID   --  112
Name --  Joe
Age  --  16
ID   --  113
Age  --  20
Name --  Carlos
```

Is it possible for it to look like this:

```
ID -- Name -- Age
112-- Joe  -- 16
113-- Carl -- 20
```

Using the first column as a guide to place the row values?

Comment: Search for (dynamic) `PIVOT`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can transform data from multiple rows into columns. In SQL Server you can use the [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) function to transform the data from rows to columns:

it looks like :

```
select id, name, age
    from
    (
      select col1, col2
      from yourtable
    ) d
    pivot
    (
      max(col2)
      for col1 in (id, name, age)
    ) piv;
```

**Updates:**

to return all the rows(i mean all data),you should use

```
select id, name, age
    from
    (
      select col1, col2, row_number() over(partition by yourtable.col1
                        order by yourtable.col1) seq
      from yourtable
    ) d
    pivot
    (
      max(col2)
           for col1 in (id, name, age)
    ) piv;
```

**Explanation:**

PIVOT requires the use of an aggregate function to get the result, in first case you are using the max function which, in  query, will return only one value for col2 (maximum value). we should include a column that will be used to keep the rows distinct when applying the PIVOT.

i had used `row_number()` to generate a unique value for each item in the sets. This value will then be used in the grouping aspect of the PIVOT:

Comment: I tried your code. @akhilkumar. It returned only the last row of what I desired to produce. Is there any way that I could loop through all the values.